# Determinar tempo e data de instalação de um aplicativo no Android

Tags: java, android

É possível obter a **data e o tempo** exato que o seu usuário instalou o aplicativo?

No iOS7+, você pode obter um recibo de quando o aplicativo foi baixado usando `[NSBundle appStoreReceiptURL]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Obtendo o Tempo e Data de Instalação

---

É possível obter o tempo e a data de instação da primeira vez que o aplicativo foi instalado através do `packageManager`:

```
long installTime = context.getPackageManager()
                   .getPackageInfo("com.some.package.name", 0)
                   .firstInstallTime;
```

E a sua respectiva versão:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
```

Infelizmente, essa data é resetada sempre que o aplicativo for re-instalado.

Se você usar o seguinte código

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("app.package.name", 0);
String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir;
long installed = new File(appFile).lastModified();
```

você conseguirá determinar a data de instalação do aplicativo no Android, mas o tempo irá sempre mudar quando ele for atualizado.

Comment: Machado, precisava conversar com você sobre Android, como posso entrar em contato?... dúvidas com firemonkey